# How to disable C++11 compiler warnings

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, clang++

I use a 2022 MacBook. Whenever I use certain C++ features, the G++ compiler throws things like `"warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]"`.

Needless to say, I do not feel a strong need for 12+-year backward compatibility in an ASCII-based solitaire game I plan to run on my computer and mine alone. I know I can run the command with `-w` to silence it, but is it too lofty a dream that I might be able to disable this particular warning altogether?

This isn't a duplicate because none of the existing questions offer a permanent solution.

```
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: I think this means you are compiling with `pre-c++11` as your language standard. If so, you say you don't care about 12+ year backwards compatibility, but that is what you are using. If you compile with `c++11` or later, this should go away.

Comment: If you want to use features from newer versions of the language, you should set `-std=c++<ver>`

Comment: How do you build? What options, flags and settings are you using?

Comment: How is information about what HW you use relevant to question?

Comment: @blami In this case because it's well known that the installation of g++ on a Mac defaults to C++98.

Comment: @john thanks! I was just curious why people often mention that in C++ questions. Not Apple user so I did not know.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Just `g++ name.cpp -o name.exe -Wall`  or `-w` and I should clarify that this is what I was taught to do and not anything I understand.

Comment: @SimonC's suggestion may what I end up doing if nothing better arises but I would much prefer to permanently set the version and not have to worry about it in the future.

Comment: It is strange that you are getting this warning with this modern compiler, it is more likely than another flag is implying this warning, like forcing an old standard.

Comment: @alfC It's the well known apple clang feature to default C++98.

Comment: @the-baby-is-you But that **is** how you permanently set the version. Create a Makefile/Makefile generator script and set the version **you** need for **your** software.

Comment: Just enable higher C++ standard in build settings. Latest MacOS OS has good support of C++17 features. Implementation of C++20 standard is still in progress (by all compilers).

Comment: @MarekR Cool, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the warning by using the flag -Wno-c++11-extensions when compiling your code with the G++ compiler. This will prevent the compiler from giving the "warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension" warning for range-based for loops.
Keep in mind that disabling warnings may hide important information about potential issues in your code. It is generally recommended to fix the issues that the warnings are pointing to, instead of disabling them.

Comment: Is there any reason to use this instead of, you know, `-std=c++11`?

Comment: The question is asking about how to disable a compiler warning. This answers that. Recommendations for something better can be useful, but that doesn't make this answer wrong. Someone could be stuck on an old compiler and can't use later standards (but still have access to extensions).

Comment: @DeanJohnson The answer is perhaps not wrong, but it's just bad advice. (You see that it suggests not using C++11 features just to avoid the warning?) We should be suggesting `-std=c++??` by default, and if there are problems with it, then perhaps `-Wno-...`. But is there any compiler that warns about C++?? extensions, while at the same time not offering the corresponding `-std=c++??` flag to enable them properly?

Comment: Both the question and this answer are confusing because not many know that apple clang defaults to C++98. KennyRivera might not known this. I just find out from a comment from the user 273K.